# How to have multiple values inside a hidden div in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found an example about show/hide methods and I arranged them in a way that the parent div is present in a row with another element. The HTML Code is as follows

```
      <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;margin-top:-20px" class="ui-grid-a">
        <div data-role="content" style="margin-left:0px" align="left" class="ui-block-a" data-inset="true"> 
            <br><label for="Search Results"><b><font color="black" face="verdana">Search Results</font></b></label>
        </div>            
<div id="toggle"  class="ui-block-b">
<ul>
    <li>Youtube Video Scraping</li>

        <select id="inspectionAssignmentSearchForm:assignedSeverityLabel" name="inspectionAssignmentSearchForm:assignedSeverityLabel" class="test-field-styles" size="1">   
                <option value="">-- Select Lane --</option>
                <option value="1">Red</option>
                <option value="2">Yellow</option>
        </select>

        <select id="inspectionAssignmentSearchForm:assignedSeverityLabel" name="inspectionAssignmentSearchForm:assignedSeverityLabel" class="test-field-styles" size="1">   
                <option value="">-- Select Lane --</option>
                <option value="1">Red</option>
                <option value="2">Yellow</option>
        </select>

</div>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).next("div").stop('true','true').slideToggle("fast");
    //li:hover{background:#FFFFE0}
    //li div:hover{text-decoration:none !important;}
    });
});
```

And style sheet.

```
     body{font-family:Tahoma;}
    ul{width:450px;}

    li{list-style-type:none; cursor:pointer; -moz-border-radius:0 10px 0 10px;  solid #666666; margin:2px; padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;}
    ul div{color: #666666; cursor: auto; display: none; font-size: 13px; padding: 5px 0 5px 20px; text-decoration: none; }
    ul div a{color:#000000; font-weight:bold;}
    li:after {content: "+"; padding:10px 10px 10px 0; color:red; font-weight:bold;}
    li.active:after {content: "-"; padding:10px 10px 10px 0; color:red; font-weight:bold;}
    #toggle{width:500px; margin:0 auto;}
```

Now the problem is that when I click the Parent Div, I am getting only one one drop drop box but the other drop down box is not coming.

And also I have to keep the child in such a way that it covers the whole div below, not only below parent div. Can anybody tell me how to proceed further

Comment: Can you create a fiddle because the html seems to be incorrect? There are unclosed tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap both `select` with a `div` and dont make it inside `ul` since it's invalid.

`$(this).next("div")` in `li.click` function is meant to find the `div` after `li`. But i suggested to put the `div` outside of `ul` so you need to do

```
$(this).parent().next("div")
```

Which is gonna find the `div` after `ul`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qn3L6/)**